# Compiling program that uses Lwt_term

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt, lwt

I have the following code in OCaml:

```
open Lwt
open Lwt_term

let () = Lwt_main.run (
  lwt l = Lwt_read_line.read_line ~prompt:[text "foo> "] ())
```

when I try to compile using

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package lwt cli.ml - o cli.byte
```

it I get the following error:

```
File "cli.ml", line 2, characters 0-13:
Error: Unbound module Lwt_term
```

I know it's unrelated to the problem above, but from utop I can open Lwt but I still can't open Lwt_term. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Source file is located [there](https://raw.github.com/ocsigen/lwt/master/src/text/lwt_term.mli) so I bet that you need `lwt.text` package

Answer (score 0):

Not really a real answer to the original question, but I have ended up using Core to accomplish it. The enlightenment came from finding the `readline_test.ml` file in a tests folder in the Core library (https://github.com/janestreet/core_extended/blob/master/lib_test/readline_test.ml).

Following that example it was really easy to implement readline-like functionality.